# FancyTree JS + Backbone.js - trouble loading data into FancyTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, fancytree

I've been struggling for some time now attempting to load data into FancyTree. The gist is the data is coming from a collection (Backbone) and it must (?) be either JSON or an array.

However, all attempts to get it working have fallen flat on its face that haven't been a local test using a .JSON file.

Is it possible to output data from a Backbone.js collection into FancyTree? Surely this must be possible, but I'm running into so many walls doing it.

For example, I tried feeding the source in these ways:

```
    source: $this.formattedData

    source: {
    url: $this.formattedData
    }
    source: {
    url: "$this.formattedData"
    }

(corresponding error): Uncaught Error: Not implemented
```

The JSON-->array approach fails because the keys are in quotes (fancytree expects title:"title", yet the array renders "title":"title").

Comment: can you create a fiddle to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a different way by passing an object containing nested for-loops. Not exactly graceful, but FancyTree isn't exactly flexible.